# Fixed-Point iteration method fails on converging on equation.

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems, numerical-optimization

I'm looking to solve the following equation in $x$.

$$\frac{Wa}{b} = \left((\frac{a}{b}+x)\Phi(\frac{a}{b}+x)+\phi(\frac{a}{b}+x)\right)-\left(x\Phi(x)+\phi(x)\right)$$

, where $W, a$ and $b$ are constants and known.

As I fail to solve it analytically, I tried a numerical method, the fixed-point iteration.
According to wikipedia, this numerical method can be done by the following procedure:

$x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ for $n=0, 1, 2, \dots$

So I would think that solving the following equation recursively, $x$ would converge as $n$ increases.

$$-\frac{\frac{Wa}{b} - (\frac{a}{b}+x_n)\Phi(\frac{a}{b}+x_n)-\phi(\frac{a}{b}+x_n)+\phi(x_n)}{\Phi(x_n)} = x_{n+1}$$

But it doesn't converge at all. Anyone that is more familiar with numerical analysis and can explain why it doesn't converge? Or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Would help to know what $\Phi$ and $\phi$ are. Also defining $f(x) = x \Phi(x) +\phi(x)$ and $c = a/b$ turns the problem into $W = [f(x+c)-f(x)]/c$. Did this come from some sort of mean value problem?

Comment: $\phi$ and $\Phi$ are commonly used as the standard normal probability density function and standard normal cumulative distribution function, respectively.  These symbols are used in introductory textbooks in probability and statistics.  See Devore's *Probability and Statistics for Engineering and the Sciences*, Eighth Edition, pages 153-154, or Wackerly, et. al's *Mathematical Statistics with Applications*, Seventh edition, pages 178-179.  The formulas are commonly available on the internet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\Phi(z) = \int_{-\infty}^z\frac{e^\frac{-x^2}{2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,dx=\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$
$$\phi(z) = \frac{e^\frac{-z^2}{2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$ Let $c=\frac a b$ and $k=W \frac a b$ and you look for the zero of
$$F(x)=\Bigg[\frac{1}{2} (c+x)
   \left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{c+x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)+\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}
   (c+x)^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\Bigg]-$$ $$\Bigg[\frac{1}{2} x
   \left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)+\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}
   }}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\Bigg]-k$$ for which the derivative is
$$F'(x)=\frac{1}{2}
   \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{c+x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt
   {2}}\right)\right)$$

Assuming $c>0$ and $F(0) <0$, the first iterate of Newton method is
$$x_0= -\frac {F(0)}{F'(0)}$$ and repeat
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{F(x_n)}{F'(x_n)}$$

Trying with $c=\pi$ and $k=e$, the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & -0.04927931754 \\
 1 & -0.04835262336 \\
 2 & -0.04835229602
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Working with rational numbers and arbitrary pecision, for $c=\frac{3371}{125}$ and $k=\frac{3371}{250}$, Newton iterates are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & -26.1701 \\
 1 & -10.2146 \\
 2 & -13.4840
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: So the derivative is equal to $\Phi(x+c)- \Phi(x)$, right? But it seems that the iterations can be quite unstable for certain starting values of $x$. Makes it not always converge...any comments on that?

Comment: @Steven01123581321. Could you give me a couple $(c,k)$ of your choice ?

Comment: $(c, k) = [(26.968, 13.484), (10.787, 10.716)]$

Comment: @Steven01123581321. I did not have any trouble to find $-13.484$ for the first

Comment: For the first one, I have for the first iteration $26.170...$ and then the derivative is $0.0$, so my next iteration fails...Can you share your results at the first iterations?

Comment: Thanks for the Edit! Just to be sure, you found this with the exact same procedure you describe (finding $x_0$ via the formula)?

Comment: @Steven01123581321. I just rewrote the inital estimate. May be, I had a sign error.

Comment: Ah yes, the negative sign was missing. I indeed get the same results now. For $(c, k) = [4.78, 0.23]$, I get iterations [-8.30, 1065.97, $-\infty$]. Do you get this as well? I would expect $x$ to converge to around $-5.15$

Comment: So it seems that when $x_0$ is not chosen well, it can't converge. Because when I alter $x_0$ to an arbitrary value other than $-\frac{F(0)}{F'(0)}$, it does converge but it also works the other way around. So chosing $x_0$ seems to be depending on $F(x)$ entirely...Only need to know how to chose this initial value $x_0$